# Vectorized calculation with condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to have vectorized calculation, since `apply or df.iterrows()` is slow. below code works fine, gives result as expected

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 12, 0, 5], "b": [5, 89, 45, 6], "c": [85, 23, 14, 10]})

def cal(data):
    val1 = data["a"]
    val2 = data["b"]
    val3 = data["c"]
        
    return val1+val2, val1-val2, val1*val3
df["add"], df["subract"], df["multiply"]  = cal(df)

    a   b   c   add subract multiply
0   0   5   85  5   -5      0
1   12  89  23  101 -77     276
2   0   45  14  45  -45     0
3   5   6   10  11  -1      50
```

Now I want to have val1, val2, val3=0 whenever any of the rows of column `a` in dataframe is 0. below is the code

```
def cal_with_zero(data):
    if data["a"] == 0:
        val1 = 0
        val2 = 0
        val3 = 0
    else:
        val1 = data["a"]
        val2 = data["b"]
        val3 = data["c"]
        
    return val1+val2, val1-val2, val1*val3

df["add"], df["subract"], df["multiply"]  = cal_with_zero(df)
```

I get error on code line `if data["a"] == 0:`

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

what I want as result is

```
    a   b   c   add subract multiply
0   0   5   85  0   0       0
1   12  89  23  101 -77     276
2   0   45  14  0   0       0
3   5   6   10  11  -1      50
```

I want to have a vectorized approach instead of `apply or df.iterrows()`. and i want to have function `cal_with_zero`, since in  passed dataframe there are lot more conditions which determines value of val1, val2, val3 in actual code due to which I was unable to use `np.where`, may be I missed something doing it. but calling `cal_with_zero` with whole dataframe as argument is necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's where function for this.  np.where is awesome.  you put in your condition, then what you want to set when that condition is true, then what you want to set when your condition is false.  For your case.

```py
import numpy as np

select_condition = df['a'] == 0

df['add'] = np.where(select_condition, 0, df['a'] + df['b'])
df['subtract'] = np.where(select_condition, 0, df['a'] - df['b'])
df['multiply'] = np.where(select_condition, 0, df['a'] * df['c'])
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to call function `call_with_zero`  in np.where and assign value in `df["add"], df["subract"], df["multiply"]` . since in original code there are lot more condition for passed dataframe in function which decides value of val1, val2, val3

Answer (score 0):

With single [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) clause:

```
df["add"], df["subract"], df["multiply"] = np.where(df['a'].eq(0), 0,
                                                    [df['a'] + df['b'], 
                                                     df['a'] - df['b'], 
                                                     df['a'] * df['c']])
```

---

```
    a   b   c  add  subract  multiply
0   0   5  85    0        0         0
1  12  89  23  101      -77       276
2   0  45  14    0        0         0
3   5   6  10   11       -1        50
```

Comment: is there a way to call function `call_with_zero`  in np.where and assign value in `df["add"], df["subract"], df["multiply"]` . since in original code there are lot more condition for passed dataframe in function which decides value of val1, val2, val3

Comment: @young_minds1, 1) read `numpy.where` doc;  2) so show those "more conditions"  to show how they define val1, val2, val3